# How can one see who deleted a chat message?

Tags: support, chat

Example:

[image: IMG:]

How can one see who deleted a chat message?

I couldn't find the information in the [history page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/64322151/history) ([mirror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEyyD.jpg), [mirror with the entire history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbHek.jpg)). I am interested to know how to do it for my own deleted chat messages as well as for other users' deleted chat messages.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your own screenshot shows who deleted the message. It looks like you have DarkReader or something similar enabled, though, which makes it much harder to see the text for some reason. Here's a screenshot without it:

[image: deleted chat message history, with the item "Feeds: deleted this message"]

(Pay no attention to the "Purge" button in the screenshot. We usually avoid purging people...)

If you look at the latest item in the message history, which is shown at the top of the "Message history" section, you can see that it has a "deleted this message" item. The deletion is attributed to "[Feeds](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-2/feeds)".

When a message is deleted via flags - either enough people raising a flag or a single moderator flagging it - the message is automatically deleted by the "Feeds" user, much like posts flagged as spam are deleted by Community on the main site. Chat messages deleted like this also impose a 30-minute suspension, which is added to the length of any existing suspension.

You cannot see who raised the flags that got the message deleted.

If a message was manually deleted by a moderator, then it would show the mod's name instead of Feeds.

To view the history of a deleted message, including who deleted it, you must be at least one of: a.) the person who wrote the message; b.) a Room Owner of the room the deleted message is currently in; c.) a moderator with moderator capabilities in that room.